# React Native custom cross-platform dropdown select element

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have searched quite thoroughly with not much luck. I am having trouble implementing a simple custom dropdown select element for my application.

I am hoping for a cross-platform (iOS & Android) solution like the simple custom JS dropdown featured here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

**Is this something I should just be creating myself with react native views and some state? I'm still trying to get a feel of what solutions are unrealistic. Could anyone give me an example from a professional project?**

I am trying to avoid using the native Picker from here since I cannot style them to match my designer's needs. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-picker

I tried this package but it seems to be having trouble with the latest versions and I need something reliable. https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown
I was also looking at this package as it seems to be nearly perfect for my needs but again it has not been updated in 2 years https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this in my project and it works perfectly:

https://github.com/mrlaessig/react-native-autocomplete-input

you can just use the `onFocus` prop to make it dropdown with a click instead of when the user firsts typing and `onEndEditing` prop to hide it when the user selects an option.

here's my full implementation for reference, I had to go into the code a bit to check for these props since the documentation didn't include it.

```
<Autocomplete
        data={filterNames()}
        placeholder={'Who are you here to see?'}
        onChangeText={item => setTextAndShowResults(item)}
        onFocus={() => setHideResults(false)}
        onEndEditing={() => setHideResults(true)}
        defaultValue={getDefaultValue()}
        keyExtractor={(item, i) => {
          return item.id;
        }}
        returnKeyType={'next'}
        listStyle={styles.listStyle}
        inputContainerStyle={styles.borderWidth0}
        style={styles.autoCompleteButtonStyle}
        hideResults={hideResults}
        renderItem={({ item, i }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setTextAndHideResults(item)}>
            <Text style={styles.listTextStyle}>{item.name}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
/>
```

Comment: I was looking at that package as well but it seems to be a search input and I require the equivalent of an HTML select element type of thing.

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach Check out the edit, there's a few more props they don't mention in the docs that will enable you to set it up that way.

Comment: My implementation DOES use the typing search as well to filter results but you could just omit that part.

Comment: I got it working and seems pretty good except I am getting `componentWillReceiveProps` depreciation warning which is always a put-off.

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach Ya I forked and edited it to get rid of that. anyway, can you mark my answer accepted? Trying to get my points up there, thanks!

Comment: Do you know of a way to disable the text input and keyboard from showing? That is a dealbreaker for me.

Comment: Sure, just set `editable={false}` and set `hideResults={aStateBooleanToggle}` then use a separate `TouchableOpacity` or similar overlayed on the input field to toggle `aStateBooleanToggle` to true/false. Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Cool, I just ended up feeding my own <View> component as the input render! I think this will work great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to go with something out there, as I will generally make implementation quicker for you, although as you say there might be a trade off in styling.

I've recently been in the situation a few times where I've really had to look hard for good, maintained components for React Native, but they certainly exist.

I've been successfully using react-native-paper recently. You could consider their accordion drop down list but may not suit in styling as it follows material UI guidelines.

https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/